# Touchpad, Horizontal Scrolling, VMWare Guest

Tags: touchpad, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on 64-bit on VMWare Player (17.0.1 build-21139696).
My problem is horizontal scrolling in browser i.e. Chrome, Edge and Firefox and latest Opera.

My laptop has touchpad and my machine is Dell G3-15. Vertical scrolling works fine but horizontal scrolling does not work at all and I find myself looking for scrollbars which nowadays are getting invisible in all the websites.

On my host machine where WIndows 10 is running, Horizontal as well as vertical scrolling works fine with no issues. I have also noticed that on other machines, installations of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or higher, do not suffer from this so,

- this is not a hardware problem as Host machine has no issues.
- this is not a browser problem as it is happening on all the browsers on guest machine but not on host
- this is not a Ubuntu specific problem as other installation of ubuntu (directly on hardware) do not have this issue.

I presume this must be a vmware specific problem. I have VmWare tools installed (at least that's what I believe). Have searched for this on various forums but did not find any answers that could solve the issue.

Can anyone guide me how can I fix my problem?
If you need more info about the hardware, OS etc  do let me know and I 'll add more details to the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just noticed the exact same thing. I switched from VirtualBox to VMware with the same guest image and the two-finger stopped working only in the horizontal direction. Happens in Libra office calc as well as browsers